# R proxy settings at work block me from connecting to internet when at home even when proxy settings disabled

Tags: r, ubuntu, proxy, rstudio

I have a laptop that I use at work and for this I need to use our work proxy. I am using Rstudio and ubuntu 18.04. I copied these lines in .RProfile:

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy='http://myproxy:3128')
Sys.setenv(https_proxy='http://myproxy:3128')
```

When I am at work rstudio is able to connect to internet, but when I'm home, rstudio is not able to connect to Internet even when I delete the above lines fom .RProfile.
I have also tried setting 'No proxy' in ubuntu proxy settings.
Does anyone have a solution?